# in a class cant make input array equal to another array

Tags: java

So i have this code which is going to convert Strings to integers, quicksort it, and then turns those integers into strings. the code works no problem but then i want to try to put integers to strings into the same input array as their was instead of making  whole other array, that did not work, as it didnt even change the input. so instead i made the int to string array method return it to me in a new array, which when debugged was exactly how i wanted it to be. and then i made it so the input array is equal to that new array i put it in, and now the return is a whole bunch of jumbled letters?

```
public class runner
{
    static void singleletterarrayalphabeticalorganizer(String[] a)
    {

   int[] number = stoianditos.singlestoi(a);//makes the string into an integer
    quicksort.sort(number,0,a.length-1);//quicksorts the integers
    String[] a1 = stoianditos.singleitos(number);//makes the integers into strings
    // i tried to put a intead of a1 but it gave me the same result
    a = a1;
    //PROBLEM AREA: suppoused to make the input given the same as a1 so i dont have to make a new array in the main class(if thats where im running it) instead of using the already exsisting array
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change parameters that are passed in to a method.  If you want to pass back the sorted array of strings, change the return type of your method to "String [] " instead of "void " and then do a "return a1;"

Comment: but that is nt what i want to do, i just want to change the array it self

Comment: You can change `a` to point to `a1`, but you cannot pass this change back to the caller, because Java is "pass-by-value."  The value of `a' passed to the method `singleletterarrayalphabeticalorganizer` cannot be modified.  You can modify the array that it points to, though.

Comment: You can change `a` to point to `a1`, but you **cannot** pass this change back to the caller, because Java is **pass-by-value**. The value of `a` passed to the method `singleletterarrayalphabeticalorganizer` cannot be modified. You can modify the array that it points to, though.

Answer (score 0):

For the converter from integer t string I'll make it so that it will also take in a int array, and instead of it returning a new array I'll make it just change the string array.